# UPI Deep Link payment declined

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, upi

I don't know whether its right place to ask this question or not, rather I don't know where to ask this question.

I am developing an app in flutter , For in app purchase I am trying to implement UPI payment . I also got a few plugins to do so , But when I am testing, I am getting  declined my transaction. I am trying to get UPI payments through PhonePe in my app. I don't know what is the exact reason to decline the transaction. Do anyone know about this ? Does it need any special permission or anything else ?

which plugin I am using that showing example transaction successfully.Then where am I going wrong ?

Here is the screenshot of the failed transaction [image]

here is the response I got `txnId=YBL02b309a0fff447f6b1d83d7cf1e4e75e&txnRef=test01&Status=Failed&responseCode=01`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution, I was using personal UPI address. It needs a merchant UPI. Without merchant UPI its not possible to get payment through deep-linking. Using merchant UPI its working fine.

Comment: How did you find merchant UPI Id?

Comment: register as a marchant in upi providers business app, and use your terminal id as your upi id, there is no need to use your merchant id, although you will get it in your business app

Comment: We created a merchant account but couldn't fie terminal id. How did you find terminal id?

Comment: in which company ?

Comment: can you please explore your solution? what do you mean by merchant upi

Comment: @rinkesh register yourself as a marchant on upi app, you will get terminal and upi id for your business use that upi address

Comment: Hi @MijanurRahaman, is it still working what is the intent url you are using ?

Comment: it was a test app. it was working fine with marchant id, you  can check it yourself

Comment: Didn't find terminal ID in G-Pay App,

Comment: @GiruBhai Terminal Id is same as your business UPI Id, personal UPI Id is not allowed

Comment: Thanks !, have tried but still it's  not working...I have also tried the link generated from QR code but at Gpay, Amazon transaction declined. can you pelase share the sample working link.

Comment: @GiruBhai I was trying this project long time ago, I have forgot what was I doing actually, and didnt backup the codes in repository, sorry for that