# UPI Deeplink not working as hyperlink but works as a qr code

Tags: deep-linking, upi

I have made a website that directly promopts to open UPI apps on user's phone and fills payee details automatically. I used the `upi://` url scheme to achieve this.
If you suffix your friend's vpa to upilink.tk (it'll open a payment page for you to pay your friend).

[image]

The pay button (a link with `href` to `upi://pay?pa=YourVPA@upi&pn=Receiver&tn=&am=&cu=INR`
prompts to open UPI apps and take you to payment page.
[image]
However the payment always fails citing weird reasons.

Reason cited in paytm app
[image]

In phonepe:
[image]

The interesting thing is, if you open the website on a desktop (or in desktop view on mobile) it'll encode the exact same url into a QR code (you can verify that by a QR code scanner) but if you try paying by scanning the qr code in a UPI app, it succeeds.

So my question is why does it fail when the exact same link is in a href tag instead of a qr code?
(This exact same thing happens with Mubikwik's mpay.me I guess they're unaware of it)

Note: I'm not providing the UPI addresses I used for testing (for security reasons). If you want to test please use yours or your friends'.

Answer (score 0):

Answer at [UPI Deep Link payment declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573022/upi-deep-link-payment-declined) seems to suggest that for UPI Deep Link to work, payee UPI VPA has to be a merchant address.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Already tested with a Bharatpe merchant.

Comment: it working on phonepe business. if dont work contact customer care and they will activate it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with Merchant account tooo!
Resulted in fail and at last I observed that if we scan it through any UPI apps the payment will work else if we scan or open link from outside UPI app it shows some kind of error !!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).